# How to get name of the emp whose salary is gretear than average salary of depatment in HIVE

Tags: hadoop, hiveql

```
Dept_id  Emp_name  Sal
1        amit      2500 
2        neha      3600
3        ankit     4500
```

Need to find the name of employee whose salary is greater than average salary of the whole department. using hive.

Answer (score 2):

Hive has restrictions while using subqueries.... we can solve your issue using the below query... change the column names as per your table...

SELECT * 
FROM employee s JOIN (SELECT s2.deptid deptid, avg(s2.salary) sal from employee s2 group by deptid) s3 ON s.deptid =s3.deptid WHERE s.sal > s3.sal;

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$sql = "select e.Emp_name from Employee e where e.sal> (select avg(sal) from Employee where dept_id = e.dept_id group by dept_id)";
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks but I need to write query in Hive not in RDBMS.

Answer (score 1):

What is your hive version?

In hive 13.0 version , it is possible  . Refer the below link
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SubQueries

Answer (score 1):

Try below the Hive query

```
SELECT e.Emp_name FROM Employee e WHERE e.Sal > (SELECT AVG(Sal) from Employee WHERE Dept_id = e.Dept_id GROUP BY Dept_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you are looking for is subqueries just like gopi suggested.
Try this.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Employee e 
WHERE e.Sal > 
(
  SELECT AVG(Sal) 
  from Employee 
  GROUP BY Dept_id
  Having Dept_id = e.Dept_id 
);
```

Input

```
1        amit      2500 
1        neha      3600
1        ankit     4500
```

Output

```
1        neha      3600
1        ankit     4500
```